# .as 1046: Type was not found...:ResultEvent and FaultEvent

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

```
import mx.rpc.soap.*;
import mx.rpc.AbstractOperation;
import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

public class MainDocument extends MovieClip {

    something.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, DisplayError);

    somethingElse.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, ParseGameSources);

    function DisplayError(evt:FaultEvent):void{
       //do something
    }

    function ParseGameSources(evt:ResultEvent):void{
       //do something
    }
}
```

I have 6 total functions that use ResultEvent or FaultEvent like the 2 above, they all get the error "1046:Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Result{or Fault}Event."

Every answer I have come across simply says to import, what I am already importing.

This is in CS5.5

Answer (score 0):

[ResultEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html)/[FaultEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/FaultEvent.html) are Flex classes, not base Flash classes. In order to use them, you'll need to be using the Flex framework.

If you follow the provided links, Adobe's language reference tells you:

> Language Version:     ActionScript 3.0
>   Product Version:  **Flex 3**
>   Runtime Versions:     Flash Player 9, AIR 1.1

---

[This Adobe reference on Flash projects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7effa.html) should point you in the right direction for using Flex SDK classes in Flash CS5. (look aaaaaaall the way down at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in Adobe Flash CS6 with the following:

File > Publish Settings > (Script: Actionscript 3.0) "Wrench Icon" > Library Path Tab > Click the "+" (Plus) icon to add a new item. > Click the (Folder Icon) to Browse to Path >

Then add this path:

Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs

This will increase you swf file size by about 150kb, but now you can compile!